# Error HH411: The library openzeppelin-solidity is not installed. Try installing it using npm (for old 0.5.0 solidity code)

Tags: solidity, openzeppelin, openzeppelin-contracts, solidity-0.5.x

I have solidity project with files like

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

import "openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/ownership/Ownable.sol";
```

When I try to compile, I get error on not installed library

```
npx hardhat compile                
Error HH411: The library openzeppelin-solidity, 
imported from contracts/....sol, is not installed. 
Try installing it using npm.
```

I have tried installing

```
npm install @openzeppelin/contracts
```

and v3.1.0 that is proper match for solidity v0.5.0

```
npm install @openzeppelin/contracts@3.1.0
```

But get the same error.

So what is this `openzeppelin-solidity` library, and how to install it?

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to @zmy comment, pointing to https://www.npmjs.com/package/openzeppelin-solidity.

2.3.0 is earliest version on npm registry as "@openzeppelin/contracts"
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@openzeppelin/contracts
openzeppelin-solidity has older versions
https://www.npmjs.com/package/openzeppelin-solidity

So installation should be like

```
npm i openzeppelin-solidity@2.2.0
```

and version in range 2.1.0-2.5.1 (for solidity v0.5.0)

2.1.0  is first version to target solidity v0.5.0
https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#210-2019-01-04
3.1.0 is Last openzeppelin-contracts version to work with solidity v0.5.0
https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#320-2020-09-10
3.0.0 (2020-04-20) AccessControl: new contract for managing permissions in a system, replacement for Ownable.
so Ownable is not available since v3.0.0
https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#300-2020-04-20
Latest is v4.2.0 (2021-06-30), requires solidity 0.8.0 since v4.0

Comment: Very good. You explained it in great detail

Answer (score 1):

Your code is wrong. The correct code should look like this.

`import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";`

There is no such library `openZeppelin-solidity`, The correct library is`@openZeppelin/contracts`

Comment: Well, this is not wrong, but old code, actually Aave https://github.com/aave/aave-protocol, for example https://github.com/aave/aave-protocol/blob/master/contracts/configuration/LendingPoolAddressesProvider.sol#L3

The problem it has no hints of what exact version and how was installed.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/openzeppelin-solidity

This package is now published as @openzeppelin/contracts. Please change your dependency.

Answer (score 0):

I coded the import by hand and typo'd it showing this error. Correcting the spelling made it work again as it was trying to find something that didn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

For the Openzeppelin contract installed that with --force and it works fine.

npm install @openzeppelin/contracts@5.0.0 --force

Also, there seems to be a versioning issue, for the latest Openzeppelin the version of solidity to be used is 0.8.20.
it works for me this way